# On Proof Techniques

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

Clearly, there are standard ways of proving general theorems without regard to the actual subject matter.  These include, but are not limited to, proof by contrapositive, proof by contradiction, and direct proof.

However, having taking an advanced course in Real Analysis, I noticed that there are many recurring proof techniques specific to the subject matter.  The most obvious, perhaps, is the standard $\epsilon,\delta$ proof.  Another technique, often used in dealing with families of functions, are $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ arguments.  Of course, there are others, but it seems as if much of the intuition in analysis pertains to understanding these and other proof techniques.

Now, I am in an Abstract Algebra course, and I have yet to fully grasp the proof techniques or the intuition.  So, I have two questions.  One, what are standard proof techniques in Algebra (or is there a compendium of sorts for such proof techniques)?  Two, how does this generalize to other fields?  It seems as if one understand the motivation behind the proof technique, then the intuition will be easier. As such, if there is such material, I would love to delve into it prior to me actually encountering material in the course which requires it.

Many thanks.

Comment: I disagree strongly with the suggestion that "there are standard ways of proving general theorems without regard to the actual subject matter".

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Of course these ways are not unique, and not every proof  must fall within these bounds.  However, it is patently clear that a "proof by contradiction" is a standard way of proving certain theorems in all subjects.

Comment: But most (not all) proofs by contradiction can be written without using contradiction. I find that telling someone to "prove it by contradiction" is rarely helpful.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Once again, I did not say that these are necessary.  However, history has established these techniques as standard in a somewhat arbitrary sense.  Could equicontinuity be proved without $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ arguments?  Sure.  However, perhaps that technique is fairly standard because it not only proves something, but also elucidates the thing it seeks to prove.  I think it is extremely important to look at things from other angles.  But one writes a piece of music before he writes a variation on it.

Comment: In the early days of an abstract algebra class, the standard proof technique is, "apply the definitions".

Comment: In beginning Algebra, many "proof questions" are really language lessons. If one understands the relevant definition, the actual verification is usually straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you're still interested in this question! There's some great material here: http://www.tricki.org/article/Algebra_front_page. The website seems to be a ghost town these days, which is a shame, but the content doesn't go bad!